# Replicate Instagrams uitabbar notification view

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, instagram, uitabbar

I want to replicate Instagrams orange notification view. The orange view with the white heart image and the white 1 label above the tabbar. What would be the best way to implement this? I can easily create an orange rectangular view but how would I get that little orange triangle at the bottom?

Instagram's Version
[image]

What I'm trying to do

[image]

I'm not really sure how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [AMPopTip](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMPopTip) can help you.

```
let popTip = AMPopTip()
popTip.showText("Hello", direction: .Up, maxWidth: 200, inView: self.view, fromFrame: someView.frame)
```